# Disable hue nesting in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

When plotting a bar chart with Seaborn and using the `hue` parameter to color the bars according to their column value, bars with identical column values are nested, or aggregated, and only a single bar is shown. The image below illustrates the problem. Patient number 1 has two samples of `sample_type` 1, with values 10 and 20. The two values have been nested, and both values are represented as a single bar (as the average of the two).
[image: Example of what I'd like to avoid]
I'd like to avoid this nesting, and rather have something like in the image below.
[image: Example of what I'd like to achieve]
Is this possible to achieve? MVE below. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "patient_number": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "sample_type": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    "value": [10, 20, 15, 10, 11, 12]
})

sns.barplot(x="patient_number", y="value", hue="sample_type", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question can not fit a general answer. It would only work if every patient has about the same number of samples. For example, what should happen if patient 3 would have 10 samples of type 3?

Comment: Then I'd like 10 green bars at x=3. In this dataset, patients all have between 3-4 samples, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach obtains the desired plot:

- Seaborn's `hue=` parameter both defines the color and the position of the bars.
- Per patient, an extra field ('idx') contains a unique number for each of the desired bars. This field 'idx' restarts from 0 for every next patient and is added to the dataframe.
- 'idx' can then be used as `hue='idx'` to get the desired columns, although they will be colored just sequently.
- In order to get one color per sample type, an extra column now contains a factorized version of the sample types (so, 0 for the first type, 1 for the next, etc.)
- Seaborn generates the bars per hue, one for each patient. These bars can be accessed as a list via `ax.patches` If some patient doesn't have a value for a given 'idx', a dummy bar is will be added to the list.
- By iterating through the patients and then through the 'idx', all bars can be visited and colored via 'sample_type'. As the ordering of the bars is a bit tricky, an adequate renumbering is needed.
- The legend needs to be changed to reflect the sample types.

The given data is extended a bit to be able to test different numbers of samples per patient, and sample types that aren't simple subsequent numbers.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'patient_number': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'sample_type': ['st1', 'st1', 'st2', 'st1', 'st2', 'st3', 'st4', 'st4', 'st4', 'st4', 'st4'],
    'value': [10, 20, 15, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})
df['idx'] = df.groupby('patient_number').cumcount()
df['sample_factors'], sample_labels = pd.factorize(df['sample_type'])

ax = sns.barplot(x='patient_number', y='value', hue='idx', data=df)

colors = plt.cm.get_cmap('Set2').colors  # https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
handles = [None for _ in sample_labels]
num_patients = len(ax.patches) // (df['idx'].max() + 1)
for i, (patient_id, group) in enumerate(df.groupby('patient_number')):
    for j, factor in enumerate(group['sample_factors']):
        patch = ax.patches[i + j * num_patients]
        patch.set_color(colors[factor])
        handles[factor] = patch

ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=list(sample_labels), title='Sample type')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: What an excellent answer, this works flawlessly. It will take me minute to wrap my head around everything that's going on here. Thank you!