# Making a barplot with elements with different values under different conditions, where values for each element are grouped and colored by element

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

First of all I would like to say that I've been looking up for a solution for several days, and I've tried several workarounds, but I've not been able to find a proper solution to what I'm trying to do.

So, the thing is the following. I have a dataframe with some elements that have a particular value under a certain condition, and I want to make a bar plot where each element is on the X-axis, their corresponding value is on the Y-axis, and the values for each condition are one next to each other over the respective element. Also I would like to color the bars with a different color for each element, but the same color for each value of the same element. Not all elements has values for all conditions.

This is not the data I'm using, but I tried to make a minimal code as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

col1 = ["A","B","C","D","A","E","B","F","C","A", "G"]
col2 = [5,3.5,4,7,3.7,2.5,4,6,5.5,3,4.5]
col3 = ["Cond1","Cond1","Cond1","Cond1","Cond2","Cond1","Cond2","Cond1","Cond2","Cond3","Cond1"]
col4 = ["green","red","blue","yellow","green","purple","red","brown","blue","green","black"]

data = pd.DataFrame(col1,columns=["Names"])
data["Values"] = col2
data["Condition"] = col3
data["Color"] = col4


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

ax = sns.barplot(x="Names", y="Values", hue="Condition", palette=data["Color"], data=data)


plt.show()
```

The output is the following:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocrcJ.png)

I know that the "palette" argument will only color for "hue", but I left like that in purpose for this example. Also, the "color" argument would color all the bars and that's not what I'm looking for. What I want is something like this:

[Desired_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tb0i.png)

Notice that also the elements with a single bar has its bar centered, instead of having the bar to the left with the 2 slots for the missing condition being empty. But I guess that fixing that could be too much to ask haha. Also, the position of the label, or the way of labeling each condition could be like that, different or even missing, I'm not that picky with that. What I really want is to be able to color the bars for each element with the same color, and place the values for each element together.

I've read about plotting directly from pandas, or that seaborn is an overkill for a plot like this so I should be using matplotlib only instead and whatnot, but I've not been able to find a solution for this. I don't know if maybe the problem is that I should re-structure the dataframe in someway, or what.

Can someone offer me any guidance over here? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300262/disable-hue-nesting-in-seaborn

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much for your answer! It's not exactly what I was looking for, but after looking in detail into that solution I figured out what I could do for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not too much a fan of these prepackaged plot modules such as seaborn. There may be a way to do this with seaborn more readily. Here however is a matplotlib native approach.

The trick is to compute where the centers are of your labels. Then merely iterating through the conditions and keeping track of where the centers are. The results:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

col1 = ["A","B","C","D","A","E","B","F","C","A", "G"]
col2 = [5,3.5,4,7,3.7,2.5,4,6,5.5,3,4.5]
col3 = ["Cond1","Cond1","Cond1","Cond1","Cond2","Cond1","Cond2","Cond1","Cond2","Cond3","Cond1"]
col4 = ["green","red","blue","yellow","green","purple","red","brown","blue","green","black"]
data = pd.DataFrame(col1,columns=["Names"])
data["Values"] = col2
data["Condition"] = col3
data["Color"] = col4


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
# get width of bars
n_cond = data.Condition.unique().size

# get conditions
names = data.Names.unique()
names.sort()
# create centers
centers = np.arange(names.size)
# create mapping to centers
name2center = {name: center for center, name in zip(centers, names)}
name2color  = {name: plt.cm.tab20(i) for name, i in zip(names, np.linspace(0, 1, names.size))}
# plot bar per Name
for name, dfi in data.groupby("Names"):
    N = len(dfi.groupby("Condition"))
    recenter = np.linspace(- 1, 1, N) * 1/n_cond
    for offset, (x, dfj) in zip(recenter, dfi.groupby("Condition")):
        center = name2center[name] + offset
        ax.bar(center, dfj.Values, width = (1/n_cond) * .8,
               color = name2color[name])
# make new labels
ax.set_xticks(centers)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
fig.show()
```

I leave if up to you to figure out how to get rid of the the gaps in between the conditions that aren't there at the `Names` labels.

Comment: If anybody has a more clean solution, please link it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, basically the idea is to plot each bar individually according to my needs. I wanted to know if there was a "proper" way to tackle this problem, but it seems that I would have to do this workaround. Thank you so much!